# Why does my website try to connect to local host even though I put in another servername?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cpanel, web-hosting

I'm new at php websites, having only done simple HTML and JavaScript sites before, and I've created a website that runs well on localhost. It connects to the database fine and all of the php functionality works. When I tried to upload my website to a vps I've bought access to, however, I get an error saying that there was an unsuccessful attempt to connect to local host. I've changed all the information on my database connection page, however, to connect not to localhost but to the database I've set up on my server, so I don't know why the website is even trying to access localhost.

Here is my database connection code:

```
<?php
$servername = "100.100.100.100";
$username = "user_name";
$password = "password";
$database = "database_name";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Many of my pages that require this document fail to load because they do not connect to the database.

Here is one error I get:

Connection Failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

And on another page I get this:

Connection Failed: Host 'ip-100-100-100-100.ip.secureserver.net' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Another weird thing is that not all of my pages that require a database connection fail to load. Some load all of the other content after the die() function, and some do not (they don't even show an error), even though none of them have the functionality I would expect if the database connection were working.

I've been really stumped by this one, even though it may turn out to be just a simple fix. Any help is appreciated.

----------------------------------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------------

I changed the server name to localhost instead of to a specific ip address and the errors are gone, but I still have no functionality, i.e. data does not go to and from the database, I can't add new users, I can't log in, etc. I still am not sure why changing the server name got rid of the errors, though, so I'm not sure that this is good news just yet.

----------------------------------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------------

I re-uploaded the original files that I had uploaded with all the original database connection information, then let it sit overnight. They errors did not return and my database connection works fine. I have no idea why the errors showed up in the first place, so if you're looking at this post because you have a similar problem, unfortunately, I can't help you. That said, it works now. Maybe the server needed longer than I thought to get the connection and permissions in effect? That's my best working guess right now. Also, I re-added the access permissions several times, so maybe the access permissions had a typo in them that I missed on the first try, and it worked by the second try because I put them in right after deleting them and re-adding them. I'm not entirely sure, but that seems like a reasonable possibility too.

If I do ever figure out what the problem was definitively I'll add another update explaining it.

Thanks for the help, Darren.

Comment: This could have something to do with your user account's "access". Is it set to "localhost" only?

Comment: I have changed the access permissions to the database. My understanding is that I need to add a specific domain or ip address that these can be accessed from. If that's not how it's supposed to be done then that could be the problem.

Comment: That is correct. This ideally is only ever required if you have your web app and database on different servers, otherwise localhost works a treat. I see you were trying to use the root user, if your mysql is configured correctly, any remote connections would be stopped regardless. Try creating another user with the correct access permissions and go from there

Comment: My database connection document actually does use a specific username other than 'root', which is part of why I'm so confused. I don't know why it's trying to use root as the username.

Comment: At the top of your script, could you put: `ini_set('dispal_errors', 1);error_reporting(-1);` and let me know if anything pops up. Also, what version of PHP are you using?>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got it working. I'm not really sure what changed but if I figure it out I'll add an update with that information.